# How to Connect UiPath Orchestrator to MS Power Platform

Tags: powerapps, uipath

I need to get Queue items from UiPath Orchestrator and process it on MS PowerApps. Is there any way I can do it? I need to push data to UiPath Orch from MS PowerApps as well.

Comment: What did you try so far. I mean this is easy. But depends on how you want to have it. Frontend, activities or API?

Comment: I want to achieve the API connection but I'm not sure how that works. If you can refer any links that might help, that will be a lot. :)

Comment: https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/reference/api-references, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/define-blank,
Basically, create a custom connector and insert all you API routes to get the actions you need.